# Finding orbits of fundamental weights

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, root-systems, coxeter-groups

Let $\Phi$ be a classical root system and let $\omega_i $ be the i-th fundamental weight.

I need to find the orbit of $\omega_i$ by the action of the Weyl Group $W$.

How to compute it?
I'm looking in particular at the "simpler" case of the root system $A_n$.

In general a way is find a set of minimal coset representatives of $W / Stab(\omega_i)$ and looking at the images of $\omega_i$ by this elements.

But, again, usually it is not simple find the minimal cosets representative of such a quotient.

Any help or reference is well accepted

Comment: It depends on what do you man by "compute". If you look in Bourbaki's "Lie Groups and Lie Algebras", vol. 4-6, you can see what such orbits are very explicitly since $W$ is acting by permuting the coordinates and, maybe, making  some sign changes.